# ImportError, No module named rdbms_googleapi on GAE python SDK when using the remote shell

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, google-api, google-cloud-sql

We're running a Django application on AppEngine (python).

When making a query using the remote shell so the sql driver points to CloudSQL, GAE is throwing an exception:
ImportError: No module named rdbms_googleapi.

This problem affects deployed apps when using the remote shell and attempting to run SQL queries.

We tested SDKs versions 1.9.36 and 1.9.37 under Mac OS X 10.11.4

You can reproduce this bugs with the following steps:

- Have a GAE application with Django.
- Use the remote shell to connect to a running instance of the application.

  - The database engine in use is google.appengine.ext.django.backends.rdbms.
- Query the database.

The expected output is the query result, however we get:

```
ImportError: No module named rdbms_googleapi
```

This is the full traceback of the exception:

```
In [2]: MyModel.objects.get(id=1)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-d1e136dd4ed5> in <module>()
----> 1 MyModel.objects.get(id=1)

/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/django-1.5/django/db/models/manager.py in get(self, *args, **kwargs)
    141 
    142     def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
--> 143         return self.get_query_set().get(*args, **kwargs)
    144 
    145     def get_or_create(self, **kwargs):

/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/django-1.5/django/db/models/query.py in get(self, *args, **kwargs)
    396         if self.query.can_filter():
    397             clone = clone.order_by()
--> 398         num = len(clone)
    399         if num == 1:
    400             return clone._result_cache[0]

/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/django-1.5/django/db/models/query.py in __len__(self)
    104                 self._result_cache = list(self._iter)
    105             else:
--> 106                 self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())
    107         elif self._iter:
    108             self._result_cache.extend(self._iter)

/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/django-1.5/django/db/models/query.py in iterator(self)
    315             klass_info = get_klass_info(model, max_depth=max_depth,
    316                                         requested=requested, only_load=only_load)
--> 317         for row in compiler.results_iter():
    318             if fill_cache:
    319                 obj, _ = get_cached_row(row, index_start, db, klass_info,

/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/django-1.5/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py in results_iter(self)
    773         if self.query.select_for_update and transaction.is_managed(self.using):
    774             transaction.set_dirty(self.using)
--> 775         for rows in self.execute_sql(MULTI):
    776             for row in rows:
    777                 if has_aggregate_select:

/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/django-1.5/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py in execute_sql(self, result_type)
    843                 return
    844 
--> 845         cursor = self.connection.cursor()
    846         cursor.execute(sql, params)
    847 

/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/django-1.5/django/db/backends/__init__.py in cursor(self)
    324             cursor = self.make_debug_cursor(self._cursor())
    325         else:
--> 326             cursor = util.CursorWrapper(self._cursor(), self)
    327         return cursor
    328 

/usr/local/google_appengine/google/storage/speckle/python/django/backend/base.pyc in _cursor(self)
    274               "You must specify a '%s' for database '%s'" %
    275               (settings_key, self.alias))
--> 276       self.connection = Connect(**kwargs)
    277       encoders = {safestring.SafeUnicode: self.connection.encoders[unicode],
    278                   safestring.SafeString: self.connection.encoders[str]}

/usr/local/google_appengine/google/storage/speckle/python/django/backend/base.pyc in Connect(driver_name, oauth2_refresh_token, **kwargs)
    165       found in storage and no oauth2_refresh_token was given.
    166   """
--> 167   driver = _GetDriver(driver_name)
    168   server_software = os.getenv('SERVER_SOFTWARE', '').split('/')[0]
    169   if (server_software in (DEV_SERVER_SOFTWARE, PROD_SERVER_SOFTWARE) and

/usr/local/google_appengine/google/storage/speckle/python/django/backend/base.pyc in _GetDriver(driver_name)
    142     else:
    143       driver_name = base_pkg_path + 'rdbms_googleapi'
--> 144   __import__(driver_name)
    145   return sys.modules[driver_name]
    146 

ImportError: No module named rdbms_googleapi
```

Has anyone experienced something similar? We believe the SDK is not installing all the required files.

It's worth mentioning that previous versions of the AppEngine python SDK worked correctly.

After messing around with the SDK we noticed that there is a missing file compared to previous versions.
We copied the file at https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/googleappengine/python/+/master/google/storage/speckle/python/api/rdbms_googleapi.py

into our /usr/local/google_appengine/google/storage/speckle/python/api directory and we resolved the issue.
This indicates that the GAE SDK installer is missing that file.

Comment: Can you clarify what version was ok? 1.9.35?

Comment: btw, we recommend updating to use the standard MySQLdb module: 
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-cloud-sql-announce/4m3_GPhm444
(to be clear though, I don't think the fact that rdbms driver is missing is intentional)

Comment: It looks like it was removed from the SDK around 1.9.29. Would switching to the standard MySQLdb module be a problem for you?

Comment: We'd prefer not doing it right now. We outlined a strategy for doing it though.

Comment: Is the SDK going to be fixed by adding that missing file or the fact that is missing due to obsolescence?

Comment: I can confirm that it was removed due to obsolescence. I recommend switching to the standard MySQLdb driver, it should be transparent to your application.